# Get the data between two hyphens from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the value between two hyphens from a variable.

For Example:

```
1) ACH-AG-1987

2) GN -RV-0001
```

From the above, I want to display:

`1) AG` and

`2) RV`

Comment: use explode function

Answer (score 5):

Use `substring_index()`:

```
 select substring_index(substring_index(col, '-', 2), '-', -1) as SecondValue
```

Comment: Oh man was I wrong with my answer. +1'd and deleted mine. Didn't know it was possible! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
\-(.*?)\-
```

[image]

Comment: I didnt got that (o.O) ?

Comment: it is a too simple pattern. you won't cut apple with a sword (though it will cut too), but with a knife. isn't it? :)

Comment: Tushar, in geeta it is written, "do your work, let the outcome leave to time".... (in this case, to other users)